# Unable to update related entity with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two related entities, namely Contact and Address, and I would like to update the contact entity using Entity Framework Core.

Here are my objects relations :

```
  public class Contact
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Firstname { get; set; }
     public string Lastname  { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public Address? Address { get; set; }
  }

  public class Address
  {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Street { get; set; }
     public string PostalCode  { get; set; }
     public string City { get; set; }
     public string Country { get; set; }
  }
```

I am now trying to update the address of my contact with the following EF Core method:

```
public Task<Contact> UpdateContact(int id, Contact entityContact)
{
     var dbContact = _applicationDbContext.Contacts.First(c => c.Id == entityContact.Id);
     
     if (dbContact.Address == null)
     {
        dbContact.Address = entityContact.Address;
        dbContact.AddressId = entityContact.AddressId;
     }
     else
     {
       _applicationDbContext.Entry(dbContact.Address).CurrentValues.
             SetValues(entityContact.Address!);
       _applicationDbContext.Entry(dbContact.Address).State = EntityState.Modified;
     }
}
```

When I try to execute the update command nothing get updated in the database.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. You have to call `SaveChanges()` on the context to save any changes made in the entities.

Comment: `dbContact.Address` will be NULL when you load a contact without using `Include()`, unless the referenced address is already in the context. This might result in a situation where you add or set a reference between `Contact` and `Address`, which was already set. This can also result in a situation where no value of the `Address` object is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the state to modified in EF Core, it's handled by EF state tracking.
After setting the changed properties at the end you should call the

```
_applicationDbContext.SaveChanges()
```

or

```
_applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
```

method.

Answer (score 0):

You should to mark the dbContact as modified and save the changes.

```
  public Task<Contact> UpdateContact(int id, Contact entityContact)
  {
     var dbContact = _applicationDbContext.Contacts.First(c => c.Id == entityContact.Id);
     
     if(dbContact.Address == null)
     {
        dbContact.Address = entityContact.Address;
       // dbContact.AddressId = entityContact.AddressId;  //You shouldn't need this.
     }
     else
     {
       _applicationDbContext.Entry(dbContact.Address).CurrentValues.
             SetValues(entityContact.Address!);
       _applicationDbContext.Entry(dbContact.Address).State = EntityState.Modified;
     }
     _applicationDbContxt.Entry(dbContact).State = EntityState.Modified;
     _applicationDbContxt.SaveChangesAsync();
  }
```